# How to deploy a web.py webservice on Windows 2012 rs server with IIS?

Tags: python, web-services, iis, web.py

I have a Windows 2012 server with IIS on it and i have my web.py script on it .
This script is working fine on localhost of the server but i want to deploy it to be used on internet.
As i cannot find any good documentation or sources , any help is appreciated.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

http://netdot.co/2015/03/09/flask-on-iis/ or
http://www.golden-orb.ltd.uk/running-a-python-website-using-microsoft-iis/

to use **wfastcgi** or

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingRunningRubyOnRailsOnIIS8OrAnythingElseReallyWithTheNewHttpPlatformHandler.aspx

to use the **HttpPlatformHandler with Flask and Tornado**